Best Practice for Implementing Create/Update Forms in React.js: Single File vs. Separate Files?
I'm currently working on a React.js project where I need to implement forms for creating and updating data. I'm debating between two approaches for organizing my code: having the create and update forms in a single file or separating them into separate files. I'm wondering which approach is considered best practice and what are the pros and cons of each approach?
Which approach is better, and why? Are there any other considerations or best practices I should keep in mind when implementing create/update forms?
Thank you in advance for your insights!
